# call method in container flutter

Tags: flutter, onresume

I have class called A.dart in that I am usnign Interprogressbar as below

```
new Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 0),
            child: IntervalProgressBar(
                direction: IntervalProgressDirection.horizontal,
                max: count,
                progress: count1,
                intervalSize: 2,
                size: Size(600, 10),
                highlightColor: Colors.pink,
                defaultColor: Colors.grey,
                intervalColor: Colors.transparent,
                intervalHighlightColor: Colors.transparent,
                reverse: false,
                radius: 0)),
```

Once the user clicks a button I am navigating to another class from A.dart to a class called B.dart. Once use completes process in class B.dart I ll pop the class B.dart. Again A.dart will be visible for the user. So my question us how can I restart the IntervalProgressBar with the updated value once user comes from B.dart to A,dart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can `await Navigator.push` then call `setState`

```
void _gotoB() async {
    String parameter = await Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => RouteB()),
    );

    setState(() {
      count1 = int.tryParse(parameter);
    });
  }

...  
  
RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Go back'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context, _textEditingController.text);
            },
          ),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intervalprogressbar/intervalprogressbar.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int count = 10;
  int count1 = 3;

  void _gotoB() async {
    String parameter = await Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => RouteB()),
    );

    setState(() {
      count1 = int.tryParse(parameter);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 0),
                child: IntervalProgressBar(
                    direction: IntervalProgressDirection.horizontal,
                    max: count,
                    progress: count1,
                    intervalSize: 2,
                    size: Size(600, 10),
                    highlightColor: Colors.pink,
                    defaultColor: Colors.grey,
                    intervalColor: Colors.transparent,
                    intervalHighlightColor: Colors.transparent,
                    reverse: false,
                    radius: 0)),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _gotoB,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class RouteB extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RouteBState createState() => _RouteBState();
}

class _RouteBState extends State<RouteB> {
  TextEditingController _textEditingController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
          body: Column(
        children: [
          TextField(
            controller: _textEditingController,
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Go back'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context, _textEditingController.text);
            },
          ),
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @chunchunghan great thank u its working for IntervalProgressBar. 
But its not working for new Container(
          margin: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
          child: ImageSequenceAnimator(
            "assets/images/" + ExcerciselistPojo.randomList[count1].imageUrl,
            "Pic_",
            0,
            5,
            "webp",
            3,
            isAutoPlay: true,
            color: null,
            fps: 2,
            isBoomerang: false,
            isLooping: true,
          ), Can u please check it

Comment: count1 values is updating but. How can refresh ImageSequenceAnimator?

Comment: @Gururaj, Need to reproduce, could you post your reproduce code to a new question, need to know ExcerciselistPojo.randomList  and your expected result. thanks.

Comment: You have reached your question limit. So how can post question again.